# Flutter error "Null check operator used on a null value"

Tags: flutter, api, dart, frontend

Good day, I have been having a problem when connecting API's in flutter, whenever I hot reload/restart im getting the error 'Null check operator used on a null value" Does anyone know how I can solve this?

This is my code, any help would be greatly appreciated. `

```
import 'package:ctrade/models/newsinfo.dart';
import 'package:ctrade/services/api_manager.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PostsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  //const PostsPage({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PostsPage> createState() => _PostsPageState();
}


class _PostsPageState extends State<PostsPage> {
 late Future<Welcome> _Welcome;


  @override
  void initState() {
    _Welcome = API_Manager().getNews();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold (
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('News App'),
      ),
      body: 
      Container(
        child: FutureBuilder<Welcome>(
          future: _Welcome,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 52,
                itemBuilder:(context, index) {
                var ticker = snapshot.data!.ticker;
              return Container(
                height: 100,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Text(ticker!)
                  ],
                ),
              );
            });
            } 
            else 
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          },
          
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}`
```

Comment: var ticker = snapshot.data!.ticker; -->this line causing an issue, please check the snapshot.hasData before accessing it.

Comment: is your data has list? if yes then Use ListviewBuilder To reterive the data